# Visual studio. Редактировать начальный кода/заготовки/шаблона

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Есть ли возможность установить/указать/редактировать начальный код при создании нового проекте в VS?
Допустим с этого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если да, то как?

Comment: В студии это все делается при помощи шаблонов. Вы можете сделать свой или отредактировать имеющийся ([примерный путь до файла](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072717/6808809)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ покапался в окрестностях по предложенному вами пути - ни намёка на код старта.

Comment: Ну тогда самое простое, что я могу вам посоветовать, это воспользоваться [мастером экспорта](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-update-existing-templates).